# Accessing ExecutedMojo data from Jenkins REST API

Tags: rest, maven, jenkins

I can access most of a maven build's information through the Jenkins REST API, but I've not been able to find the ExecutedMojos, which I need for their timing information.  I see that [this information is available through Jenkins' Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/maven/MavenBuild.html#getExecutedMojos%28%29), but I'm not sure how to go interacting with Jenkins programmatically either.